# How to get GPU multisampling modes descriptions?

Tags: opengl, antialiasing

I'm implementing AA in my OpenGL game and I'm using `wglChoosePixelFormatARB` to select suitable rendering context. There's a problem with selecting the right mode though.

As you may know GPUs can use various AA strategies in various combinations (MSAA, SSAA, CSAA, etc). E.g. if I request `WGL_SAMPLES_ARB = 8` I get very nice anti-aliasing, but it does disables only partially when I call `glDisable(GL_MULTISAMPLE)`, while when I request `WGL_SAMPLES_ARB = 7`, it can be disabled well.

Here's quote that I've found:

> Originally there was only multisample antialiasing (MSAA). SAMPLES was designated for the number of MSAA samples per pixel to allocate for that system framebuffer. Clean, simple.
>
> Then the GPU vendors added support for supersample antialiasing (SSAA), coverage sample antialiasing (CSAA), and combinations of the three. For instance, here are the modes available on an NVidia GTX285 on the latest OpenGL 3.3 drivers:
>
> ---
>
> AA Mode / Description
>
> - 0 - Off
> - 1 - 2x (2xMS)
> - 5 - 4x (4xMS)
> - 7 - 8x (4xMS, 4xCS)
> - 8 - 16x (4xMS, 12xCS)
> - 9 - 8x (4xSS, 2xMS)
> - 10 - 8x (8xMS)
> - 12 - 16x (8xMS, 8xCS)

So, I'm looking for a way to get AA mode description, which kinds of AA it combines. Ho do I do it?

Comment: Google indicates this quote is from [Dark Photon on opengl.org](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/170594-Multisampling-parameter-ques?p=1200144#post1200144)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there *is* no description, other than what you write, by cross-checking the relevant documentation from the relevant vendor.

Neither OpenGL or Direct3D provide any kind of documentation of what the AA mode actually *means*, unfortunately.

Comment: How do I know that i.e. in my example modes 7,9,10 are even existent and mean 8x AA? I would never have checked anything other than 1,2,4,8,16...

Comment: Well, as you found out, the modes don't have to be powers of two. So just assume there are no "gaps" in the list of modes. As for what they mean? Like I said, the only way to know is to ask NVidia and ATI. They've documented how they interpret at least some of them, so you'll have to go hunting on their websites. But the API itself won't tell you anything useful about it. (Most games just show the AA setting as a single integral quality level, or a slider, rather than actually describing the mode)

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea cos AA modes may change over time, GPU models and drivers versions. I don't plan to show AA mode description, I just like to map Low Mid High setting, but for that I need to choose appropriate quality levels.

Comment: @Krom: the best you can do is to fake it, afaik. You can assume that lower numbers mean lower quality, so 1 will be lowest quality and MAX is highest.